# Do stuff while screen is off but turn off when app goes to background

Tags: android, button, service, screen, lifecycle

I have to allow my app to do stuff when user turns screen off but i must stop service when user goes to main screen (or other app).

I tried to handle Power button but it wasn't work. 
Then i create ScreenReceiver like that:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        wasScreenOn = false;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        wasScreenOn = true;
    }
}
```

but it change **wasScreenOn** value too late (after onStop method is called)

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.i(TAG, "onStop");
    if (powerButtonClicked)
        return;
    if (mBound) {
        mMediaService.onStop();
    }
}
```

power button is always false... it changes too late

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found answer. 
All you need to do is declare PowerManager

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
```

and in onStop()

```
if (!powerManager.isScreenOn()) 
{
    // Screen is off
}
```